# What is the distance between 2 or more Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have added 2 FAB on my app (like Google Maps app, see screenshot below) and i was wondering if there is a specific distance to be respected between the 2 FAB (from a Google Design Pattern, docs, bible or whatever) or whether it is the developer who decides this distance between those buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Google developer documents on the [FAB](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button) there is no definitive answer for spacing between FAB's but it states that

> The floating action button should be placed 16dp min from the edge on mobile and 24dp min on tablet/desktop.

Knowing this you can space the buttons accordingly, using the the 16dp/24dp rule.

---

**On a side note**.

When I was working with the Google Play Editorial Board while preparing my app for feature, they specified that FAB's should be limited to one per screen. If you do need more than one maybe create a expanding menu. Something like this

[image]

Comment: This sounds good: do you have any example / tutorial of expanding menu? I noticed it on Lollipop easter egg app, so now i'm curious to try it. EDIT: found it, but it a library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button . Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No problem @jj86. You can create your own very easily. No need for a library but use whatever is easier for you!

Comment: Of course if you have your own solution, feel free to add it on your answer ;-) .

Comment: I don't have a generic solution. Mine was created for specifically two items (see it here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nasdev.colorfinder) so the code is optimised for two items. Give the library a go, looks good to me.